# App crashes when running on iPhone with violations as exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

```
    Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1e81a458 __abort_with_payload + 24
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x1e817dd9    system_set_sfi_window + 1
2   TCC                             0x20f27c4f __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 229
3   TCC                             0x20f27b6b __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 1
4   TCC                             0x20f2a383 __tccd_send_block_invoke + 339
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x1e90215f _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 47
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x1e902101 _xpc_connection_call_reply + 27
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1e72649b _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 605
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1e727a91 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 379
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1e7278b7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 107
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1e8ce937 _pthread_wqthread + 1169
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1e8ce48c start_wqthread + 8
```

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason: TCC, This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
Triggered by Thread:  1
I don't know what permissions i need to add.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

iOS 10 onwards, when you access privacy sensitive resources like camera, microphone you should add usage description text to info.plist.

This text will be shown in alert asking user to grant permission to access the resource when your code tries to access the resource for the first time.

So you should put appropriate message explaining why your app needs the resource :)

Add key NSMicrophoneUsageDescription and a text description to info.plist and it will not crash again :)

[image]

Comment: @jeeva : I must say you have great way of thanking by not accepting the correct answer which was proposed before all other answers and accepting some other answer though !!!

Comment: haha sorry bro!!i thought i could  click answer for all answers .. as every body mentiod that..but urs with picture made it very clear thank u

Comment: @jeeva : Thank you :) Fact that everybody answers for point here :) Fact that if u write correct answer be the first to do it yet won't get appreciated hurts hence said that :) Thanks a lot :) You can't accept all the answer but you can always up vote all of them :) Consider doing it :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription " in info plist which will allow to private data access from the microphone needed.