# Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I have a fairly simple app that parses a RSS feed and shows it's content in a table view. It's available on the App Store. I have Crashlytics crash reporting integrated. I recently received two reports. These are a little difficult to decipher.

This has occurred in an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.2.1.

[image]

This is from an iPhone 5 running iOS 10.2.1.

[image]

Even though it says it's crashing due to privacy violations, I'm not accessing any services that requires permission in my app.

Also searching on *com.apple.root.default-qos* lead me to believe that this may have something to do with background threads. The only place where I use a background thread is to parse the RSS feed data.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL) else {
        return
    }

    do {
        let xmlDoc = try AEXMLDocument(xml: data)

        if let items = xmlDoc.root["channel"]["item"].all {
            self.posts.removeAll()

            for item in items {
                let title = item["title"].value ?? ""
                // ...
                self.posts.append(jobPost)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.saveposts(self.posts)
                self.posts.sort { $0.publishDate > $1.publishDate }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                UIApplication.shared.toggleNetworkActivityIndicator(show: false)
                self.toggleUI(enable: true)
                if self.refreshControl.isRefreshing { self.refreshControl.endRefreshing() }
            }

        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("RSS parsing failed: \(error)")
        self.showErrorAlert(error)
        UIApplication.shared.toggleNetworkActivityIndicator(show: false)
        self.toggleUI(enable: true)
        if self.refreshControl.isRefreshing { self.refreshControl.endRefreshing() }
    }
}
```

I tested this code on my iPhone 5 running iOS 9.3.5 and simulators running iOS 10.2 but no crash occurred.

Is there any other way to track down this problem?

Comment: This looks like a permissions issue, are you sure you're not using something that requires permission and the device you're testing on already grants that permission? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39416858/1305067) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011660/app-crashes-when-running-on-iphone-with-violations-as-exception).
Also, here's Apple's [list of permissions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1937/_index.html).

Comment: I double checked everything. In my device, it has the usual Cellular Data enabled in Settings and that's it. Since my device is still in iOS 9, I tested this again by resetting the simulator that runs iOS 10.2 and reinstalled the app. Still no crash. The other thing is, if it was really a permission related crash, I'd get the whole which permission is missing error message with the crash report which I didn't in this case.

Comment: And also I should note that only two occurrences (one each) of these errors were reported. Other users are having 100% crash free sessions.

Comment: Are you using an ad framework? Make sure you've check which permissions it requires - could be occasionally serving an ad that requires some odd permission. You don't necessarily see a permission missing message - e.g. if you're trying to use CoreMotion data.

Comment: @AshleyMills Nope, no ads. I use Realm, AEXML and your Reachability library :D

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure I'm not the guilty one!  :D

Comment: haha...yeah, can't be any of the libraries as I've used them in other projects without an issue.

Comment: Worth having a scan through here and checking if you're doing something you thought didn't need approval… https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: By any chance are using a share feature to share app content such as images with social media? If you are, the `Save Image` button in `UIActivityViewController` will cause a crash if the gallery permission is not given, for example.

Comment: @paulvs I do have a share feature but I have added `saveToCameraRoll` as an excluded activity type.

Answer (score 7):

I would double check all your permissions. In my case, starting with iOS10 you need permissions to save stuff to the user's camera roll. In my app, I was showing a default share sheet and whenever a user selected "save photo" the app crashed with one of these very not helpful error messages. I added

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow you to save charts and graphs from the app to your phone.</string>
```

to my `info.plist`, `clean` & `run`. And everything the problem was solved.