# Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos SIGABRT ABORT

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, crashlytics

In my app i am using **crashlytics**, it's getting one crash report frequently. This is  Crashed:

> com.apple.root.default-qos SIGABRT ABORT 0x00000001907b7d74

I am downloading photo from server, for this i have used this following code in info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need to save photos</string>
```

But i am getting the error **CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION** + 682 frequently.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723130/crashed-com-apple-root-default-qos)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [How do I prevent a WKWebView from presenting the Camera modal if a user has denied access to the camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514435/how-do-i-prevent-a-wkwebview-from-presenting-the-camera-modal-if-a-user-has-deni) Specifically because the identifier (which I believe is an internal constant) after `TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_` is also `2.80` in your case. The short answer is: `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`

Comment: I'm not using any camera in my app. I'm using only accessing photo library. For this I'm added photo library permission in info.plist. Is it mandatory to add NSMicrophoneUsageDescription with out using camera or microphone.

Comment: Microphone permissions show up in unexpected places sometimes, like using the Camera where you can record video. If you have any web views or `SFSafariViewController`'s in your app and the user can use the camera that way, you may need the microphone permissions. I don't know of any cases where you also need it for photo library, but it may be possible. Little harm to include it in your Info.plist. It could solve your crash, and if it's not that, user's will never be prompted.

Comment: Thank you! When you switch to the video it crashes with NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this,

> Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

Specifies the reason for your app to access the user’s photo library. See [NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW17) for details.

Comment: <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need to save photos</string> Already i mentioned above code And Now I added Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description with key For saving photos. Is it enough ...for this

Comment: Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description takes permissions for all photo library related stuffs. So no need of NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription at all. And even NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription added to iOS 11, so it may create issue prior to iOS 11.

Comment: I am getting this error, The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.